# how to get the information of system log of taskscheduler under the command line with WMIC?

Tags: wmic

I need to know whether the `taskscheduler` has run successfully. I found difficult to get a return value by the `wmic` command, because they aren't included in the system, security, application hardwareevents and so on logfile. Following is my attempts:

```
wmic ntevent "eventcode=140" get message /value
```

The above code returns the message: "no instance(s) availalbe."

As I don't know which kind of logfile includes the log records of `taskschedule`, I select them by the eventcode.

```
wmic ntevent where "logfile='system' and eventcode='140'" get message /vule
```

No matter, `logfile='appliaction'` or `logfile='security'`, at the end I can't get the result I want.

What i need to point out is the log records are allocated in Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational in graphical interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `wmic` can only be used on *classic* logs. List them by 
`wmic NTEventlog get LogfileName` or by `powershell Get-EventLog -AsString -List`:

```
Application
HardwareEvents
Internet Explorer
Key Management Service
PreEmptive
Security
System
TuneUp
Windows PowerShell
```

Switch to [wevtutil](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html): `wevtutil enum-logs` enumerates the available logs and

```
wevtutil qe Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler'] and (EventID=140)]]" /uni:false /f:text
```

command could be a starting point for you. Pretty weird syntax and result hard do parse. Moreover:

> The primary focus of `WEVTUTIL` is the configuration and setup of
>   event logs, to retrieve event log data the PowerShell cmdlet
>   `Get-WinEvent` is easier to use and more flexible:

**Switch to  [powershell](http://ss64.com/ps/)**: `(Get-WinEvent -ListLog *).LogName` enumerates the [available logs](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=289626) and one can simply filter and format result from next command:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
```

For instance, to format the result in list view to see all properties:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational | Format-List *
```

Read more in [Powershell and the Applications and Services Logs](https://letitknow.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/powershell-and-the-applications-and-services-logs/).